# How to create a Flashlight in unreal that can be used in Android?

Tags: unreal-engine4

The player carries the flashlight so it is moving all the time. I'm aware of using a spotlight to make a flashlight when developing for the PC but it doesn't work for android. I have tried searching about it and all i have come across is creating a dynamic material that's applied to a certain area to give the illusion of a flashlight and it doesn't look good at all. So i would like to know if there is any other way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I think one option would be to use post processing. I am not sure is this better than using materials, but it is different (perhaps easier) way.

Here is example that I made quickly (obviously you would need to fine tune it):
[fake light GIF](https://i.imgur.com/XUjA7pk.gifv)

[image: fake light 1]

[image: fake light 2]

[image: fake light 3]

This contains ambient light and post processing effect.

**Yellow area in middle** that you see as light is not point light, it **is just effect**.

It is possible to change "light" area/intensity/color/... as well as overall darkness.

---

Also, worth mentioning, I made this quickly since I had already somewhat similar post processing effect, I just adjusted it so it look like flashlight.

You can find more information here:

- [Post Process Effects](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Engine/Rendering/PostProcessEffects/)
- [Post Process Materials](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Engine/Rendering/PostProcessEffects/PostProcessMaterials/)